# Yii2: SSL issue while trying to get Image Mime type

Tags: ssl, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i am working in yii2 and getting the following warning

> exif_imagetype(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error
> messages: error:14090086:SSL
> routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

while trying to get image mime type in the following way,

```
$image_mime = image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype(\yii\helpers\Url::home(ssl) . $promoBanner));
```

This started to occur after we configred ssl on our staging server. Any one has an idea?.

One more thing our staging server is running on Amazon EC2 and we have 2 instances 1 for cron and other for web, the images are residing on the same instance i.e Web instance.

## `EDIT`

Here is the output for the certificate locations

```
php -r "print_r(openssl_get_cert_locations());"
Array
(
    [default_cert_file] => /etc/pki/tls/cert.pem
    [default_cert_file_env] => SSL_CERT_FILE
    [default_cert_dir] => /etc/pki/tls/certs
    [default_cert_dir_env] => SSL_CERT_DIR
    [default_private_dir] => /etc/pki/tls/private
    [default_default_cert_area] => /etc/pki/tls
    [ini_cafile] => 
    [ini_capath] => 
)
```

and my `php.ini` has

```
curl.cainfo = /etc/pki/tls/cert.pem
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out that it was the absolute path that worked with the  `file_get_contents` and the `exif_imagetype()` methods dont know why but it some how wasnt accepting the url in the form `http://www.example.com/path/to/image.jpg` and i used `getcwd()` to provide the absolute url and the problem is gone.